# Bash autocomplete using codegangsta cli framework [https://github.com/codegangsta/cli]

Tags: bash, autocomplete, go

I am a newbie to golang and i am using the code gangsta cli framework [https://github.com/codegangsta/cli] to develop a command line application. I am trying to implement the autocomplete feature for the flags of the commands, but looks like it is not working as expected. Has anybody tried to implement this feature using this framework?

Here is my part of the code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "os"

    "github.com/codegangsta/cli"
)

func main() {
    app := cli.NewApp()
    app.Name = "greet"
    app.Usage = "sample command-line app by greet"
    app.Author = "abc"
    app.Email = "xyz@aaa.com"
    app.EnableBashCompletion = true
    app.Commands = []cli.Command{
        {
            Name:      "read",
            ShortName: "r",
            Usage:     "read something",
            Subcommands: []cli.Command{
                {
                    Name:   "articles",
                    Usage:  "read articles",
                    Action: readArticles,
                },

                {
                    Name:  "tweets",
                    Usage: "read Tweets",
                    Flags: []cli.Flag{
                        cli.StringFlag{

                            Name:  "account",
                            Value: "SomeThing",
                            Usage: "name of Twitter account",
                        },
                    },
                    Action: readTwitter,
                },
            },
        },
    }
    app.Run(os.Args)
}

func readArticles(ctx *cli.Context) {
    fmt.Println("Go to http://www.google.com to read articles!")
}

func readTwitter(ctx *cli.Context) {
    fmt.Printf("Go to https://twitter.com/%s to read tweets!", ctx.String("account"))
}
```

Here is the expected output:

./greet read tweets --a [TAB][TAB] does not work.

Comment: Did it work for you? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Enabling bash completion in the Go code is just one step out of two.

You need also to download and source [this](https://github.com/urfave/cli/blob/master/autocomplete/bash_autocomplete) script. After downloading, just run:

```
source bash_autocomplete
```

To make it permanent, add the above command with full path to your ~/.bashrc or ~/.bash_profile files.

Answer (score -2):

I would take a read at this part of the readme for the [cli repo](https://github.com/codegangsta/cli#to-enable).

Comment: The readme leaves a lot to be desired... For example, how to distribute this program with autocompletion (not that this topic *should* be in the scope of the README, but for the purposes of answering this question).

Comment: It sounds like you're expecting magic and/or don't understand how auto completion in various shell's work.

Comment: @DaveC I'm not expecting magic--lots of programs permit other programs/plugins to define their own behavior without any magic. I don't know how autocompletion works, but it's certainly not unreasonable that it might be a similar mechanism. A good answer would explain why a library can't deliver this functionality, and what the CLI API means by "enable bash completion" (which looks to me like it means, "set this flag to true and get autocompletion goodness!").

I'm not asking for magic, just a good answer to the question.